# How to get a NSRange Value from NSConcreteValue?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsrange, nsvalue

The code is like this. My question is how to get the `NSRange` value from the `id` type?

```
-(void)clicText:(MyLabel *)label clickedOnLink:(id)linkData{
     NSString *message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"LinkData is %@:%@",[[linkData class] description],linkData];
}
```

I get the type is `NSConcreteValue` and the data value is `NSRange:{0,4};` but how do I get the `NSRange` from the `NSConcreteValue`?

I have already tried the `[NSValue valueWithNonretainedObject:linkData];` but it does not make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `rangeValue` method:

```
NSRange range = [linkData rangeValue]; // assume linkData is NSValue
```

Comment: it's done. i do not realized the id including so many methods itself before; thanks!

Comment: `id` doesn't include any methods really. `rangeValue` is being called on an instance of `NSConcreteValue`.

Comment: do you mean that the method is work in the NSConcreteValue?  when i type "[id " in the xcode,it prompts many method,but how the xcode knows what kind of method i can use?

Comment: It doesn't with `id`. `id` could be anything as far as Xcode knows. If you use a method that doesn't exist on the actual object, your app will crash with an "unknown selector" error.